# Json.net: How to detect if a property is at input during deserialization?

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, json.net

I have the following class:

```
[DataContract]
public class MyMessage
{
    [DataMember(IsRequired = false)]
    public string Foo { get; set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = false)]
    public string Bar { get; set; }

    public void NotifyPropertyFound( string propName )
    {
        ...
    }

}
```

I need to deserialize the following Json input:

```
{ "Foo": null,
  "Melda": 123
}
```

I need the deserializer to call the method `NotifyPropertyFound` twice: once with argument `"Foo"` (which I do have in my class) and once again with argument `"Melda"` (which I don't have).

I'm playing with `IContractResolver` and `JsonConverter`, but none of them seems to provide an opportunity to call the `NotifyPropertyFound` method. Any idea?

**EDIT**

I can detect `"Foo"` using an `IValueProvider`. But I still need to detect `"Melda"`.

Comment: To the guy that promptly issued a down vote making this question -1 without explaining anything - you really helped a lot. I hope you are happy now.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can change the property to be backed by a private field instead of an auto property. You can then try to call that method in the setter that is called by the default deserializer.

Another alternative is to write your own deserializer.

Comment: Using a private field would allow me to detect `"Foo"`, but I need to detect extraneous properties like `"Melda"` in example.

Comment: Is this initiated by JavaScript? If so you could potentially run the checks in the javascript object before pushing it to the server

Comment: Thanks, but it's not initiated by JavaScript. It's a REST API that receives a JSON blob as input.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the result you want using a custom `JsonConverter` like the following:

```
class MyMessageConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return (objectType == typeof(MyMessage));
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JObject jo = JObject.Load(reader);
        MyMessage msg = jo.ToObject<MyMessage>();
        foreach (JProperty prop in jo.Properties())
        {
            msg.NotifyPropertyFound(prop.Name);
        }
        return msg;
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Demo:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string json = @"{ ""Foo"": null, ""Melda"": 123 }";

        JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
        settings.Converters.Add(new MyMessageConverter());

        MyMessage msg = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyMessage>(json, settings);
    }
}

[DataContract]
public class MyMessage
{
    [DataMember(IsRequired = false)]
    public string Foo { get; set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = false)]
    public string Bar { get; set; }

    public void NotifyPropertyFound(string propName)
    {
        // Write to the console each time this method is called
        Console.WriteLine(propName);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Foo
Melda
```